# Git hub merge went a bit wrong

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Colleague 1 pushed his changes to the server.
Colleague 2 pulled the changes from the server. We went through the conflicts and resolved them.

**We had made a mistake somewhere.**

We ended up reverting to an old commit on Colleague 2s computer and forced a push to the remote.
However, when we went to Colleague 1s computer, it wanted to push his changes still...

I think the problem is that the push that was forced placed commits that were older than the commits on the other colleagues local... and so on his source tree, he still has the most recent changes and thus should be pushing to the server... but really we want those commits to be behind the copies on the server so he can deal with conflicts.

Firstly, sorry if the above is unclear...
Secondly, do you have any ideas about this situation?

We use SourceTree if that helps.

R = remote
M = Colleague 2
K = Colleague 1
BD = Developer branch
B1 = A feature (source tree)

[image]

Comment: Are you using independent working spaces, and a central git server (remote)? If so, sounds like Colleague 1 still has the most recent (and the one you want) commits. Force push Colleague 1's changes to remote, then wipe `--force` from your memory.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm going to upload a diagram aswell as i'd like to know what went wrong in the original problem.

Comment: Okay, from my understanding after reading the visual aids, `K` and `R` is still all good, right? Did `M` reset the development branch with the refs fetched from origin? As in `git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/development` or was it a pull - `git pull origin development`?

Comment: +1 for the _gorgeous_ hand-written graphs :D

Comment: Now talking more seriously, I think it would be best to see an extract of the commits graph with the branches of each of those remotes.

Comment: I'm going to construct the issue on a test repository... Haven't got the time right now and made them merge manually... Going to get this right, then hopefully can solve the issue next time... I'll also be able to place more information here for future people with same issue.